# Example code for a neural networl learning using two-dimensional arrays on node.js

Tags: arrays, node.js, multidimensional-array, neural-network

Please, use language node.js, give me an example of a library and code on it for program can of learning two-dimensional arrays using neural networks. 
Example:

```
Train data set:
input: [ [0,1] , [0,1,0] ] output 1
input: [ [1,0] , [1,0,1] ] output 0
input: [ [1,0] , [0,0,1] ] output 0
input: [ [0,1] , [1,1,0] ] output 1
Ask array:
input: [ [1,1] , [0,0,0] ] result 0.97
```

Comment: You asked exactly the same question with python, and it was closed. This one will also be closed for the same reason. Please do not post off-topic questions.

Comment: @MatiasValdenegro Why you think, that this question off-top? Here is node, there is python. I want see example program whose can resolve this task. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: It is too broad, its not a specific questions, there are too many possible answers.

Comment: @MatiasValdenegro please give me at least one. Well, ok, next time it will be more specific ...